# Best approach to build a VBA UDF to retrieve data from site

Tags: vba, excel

I need to build a Excel VBA user defined function that retrieve data from a webpage like this one:

https://www.comdinheiro.com.br/Clientes/ServerToExcel/S2E_TESTANDO001.php?func1=retorno&func2=retorno(01/01/2011,16/03/2015,ptaxc,todos)

I know I could create a query for each function's call, but that would result in too many queries on the worksheet. I could also open a IE and "read" the html script to get the data, but that would take to much time. So what are the other possibles ways I am missing to solve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best approach but you could use the MSXML2.XMLHTTP object to request the site.

Example:

[image]

Formula in B2 downwards is `=getResult(A2,B2)`.

The UDF `getResult` is:

```
Public Function getResult(dFromDate As Date, dToDate As Date) As Double

 Dim sFromdate As String, sToDate As String
 sFromdate = WorksheetFunction.Text(dFromDate, "dd/mm/yyyy")
 sToDate = WorksheetFunction.Text(dToDate, "dd/mm/yyyy")

 Dim sURL As String, sArguments As String, sRequest As String

 sURL = "https://www.comdinheiro.com.br/Clientes/ServerToExcel/S2E_TESTANDO001.php"
 sArguments = "?func1=retorno&func2=retorno%28" & sFromdate & "," & sToDate & ",ptaxc,todos%29"
 sRequest = sURL & sArguments

 Dim httpObject As Object
 Set httpObject = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
 httpObject.Open "GET", sRequest, False
 httpObject.send

 Dim sGetResult As String
 sGetResult = httpObject.responseText
 sGetResult = Replace(sGetResult, ".", Application.DecimalSeparator)

 getResult = CDbl(sGetResult)

End Function
```